# Why do I get different results if I put a wildcard in a string BEFORE a LIKE as opposed to a string AFTER a LIKE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I ran these two queries in PostgreSQL and got different results. I was wondering if someone could explain why. Is this the same in MicrosoftSQL, MySQL, and other databases?

```
select 'teststring%' like 'teststring'; --returns False
select 'teststring' like 'teststring%'; --returns True
```

Comment: thank you for the edits, Celeo

Comment: After the `like` pattern, the `%` character is considered as `escape  character`. but it is not the same case for the first `%` (which is before `like`)

Answer (score 3):

Because `'teststring%'` is actually not like `'teststring'`.

But '`teststring'` is like `'teststring%'`.

This should happen in every database.

`LIKE` operator is not commutative. If the rightside string has no wildcard character (ampersand or underscore) it behaves as `=` (as a side effect).

Algorithm for `LIKE` handles the rightside this way:

- %: matches any number of any characters (could match none);
- _: matches any character (no more, no less), but just exactly one;
- any other char: matches that character solely.

The leftside string has no special meaning to any character.

Comment: interesting.  So what can you compare the `LIKE` operator to when there _is_ a wildcard in the rightside string?

Comment: You have to add it as `\%`

Comment: so there are no wildcards leftside string?

Comment: You'll have to escape it, as Houari just noted. BUT I think this escape is database dependent.

Comment: In SQL Server, for example, the escape character must be specified in an `ESCAPE` clause: [LIKE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933232%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: So it doesn't act as a wildcard if it's in the leftside?  select 'teststring\%' like 'teststringjjjj'; -- returns False

select 'teststring%' like 'teststringjjjj'; -- returns False

Comment: No, it doesn't. Every character on the leftside (including % and _) is taken as itself and can be matched only by themselves (in case of % and _ they must be escaped on the rightside) or by an wildcard on the rightside.

Answer (score 1):

After the [`like`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-matching.html) pattern, the `%` character is considered as `escape  character`. but it is not the same case for the first `%` (which is before `like`)

to escape the character `%` you have to add `\` (This the default one in PostgreSQL, you can choose another using the [`escape`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-matching.html) clause): `\%`

For example:

```
select 'teststring%' like 'teststring'; -- returns false
select 'teststring' like 'teststring%'; -- returns true
select 'teststring%' like 'teststring%'; -- returns true
select 'teststring%' like 'teststring\%'; -- returns true
```

Comment: If it's not considered as `escape character`, then what is it considered as?

Comment: @zebrainatree I bring you some example in my answer!

Comment: Humm, PostgreSQL also has an `ESCAPE` clause: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-matching.html.

Comment: i see your examples, but the '%' symbol in the leftside string is not operating as a wildcard, it is simply a character.  Is that true?  Can you not have wildcards on the leftside of a LIKE?  that's what @rslemos said

Comment: @zebrainatree Why would you like that wildcard on the left ?! What do you really want to achive ?

Comment: `%` is never an "escape character" in SQL.